# How to handle multiple syntax command line arguments using boost.program_options

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options, command-line-arguments

Consider a utility which can be used in different modes, like:

utility.exe --mode x (one list of arguments expected)
utility.exe --mode y (different list of arguments expected)

How can i write code for parsing such arguments in Boost.Program_Options???

Answer (score 0):

You could parse this mode out yourself (or with boost program options use a way that ignores unknown options), and then depending on that outcome, you could feed the cmd line arguments to different boost program option objects.